# PhoneGap, Iphone, Angular digest loop Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-digest

i have an angular application that works great on my browser.
(ALSO the browser of my iphone5)
The problem happens only when i am running it on my phone using PhoneGap.

is each time i am moving between views (ALL VIEW in my application) i am getting this similar error...

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A5%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22207.20000000000002%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22match.type%20%3D%3D%20'text'%22%2C%22newVal%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22match.type%20%3D%3D%20'image'%22%2C%22newVal%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(a)%7Breturn%20d(a)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%22height%22%3A%22207.20000000000002px%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22dialogLabelStyle%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22%7B'showing'%3A%20matchDlgShowing%2C%20'allow-.............(and so on and so fourth)
```

1) Inside the browser of my phone, i am not getting any error

2) i am NOT using $scope.$watch at all

3) i disabled FastClick

4) all the data in the view are coming for services that holds static JSON, for example :

```
someApp.service('BaseContentService', function(ContentNumbersService){

    .......

    this.getSomeData = function() {
        return this.levels.levelsCount;
    };

});

//Inside controller
$scope.data = BaseContentService.getSomeData();
```

But each time i am moving between views i am getting this error

Can you help me please

Comment: i was thinking maybe its related to some phone gap plugin, but after removing them still i get error, errors that my application is slow. is there something wrong with my question am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from angular 1.4.4 to angular 1.4.6 solved the problem!

thank for the rating...

Comment: I was experiencing the exact same thing.  I upgraded AngularJS and am no longer receiving infdig error